# A polynomial that sends a finite amount of units to their inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and suppose $S\subset R$ is a finite set of units from $R$. I want to prove that there exists a polynomial $f\in R[X]$ such that $f(s)=s^{-1}$ for all $s\in S$. I've actually found a formula for such $f$ which should work, but it's terribly long and I'm not getting the impression that I'm supposed to look for such a long formula because of it. Also, it is a nightmare to prove that it is correct, so can anyone help me with a proof without trying to get such a large formula? I don't really know where to start.

Comment: What is the formula for two units?

Comment: $f(x)=-s^{-1}t^{-1}x+s^{-1}+t^{-1}$, where $S=\{s,t\}$

Comment: Try induction on the cardinality of $S$.

Comment: Surprisingly, Lagrange's interpolation in this case gives an invertible denominator $s_1 s_2 \cdots s_n$. See [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=InterpolatingPolynomial+%5B%7B%28s%2C1%2Fs%29%2C%28t%2C1%2Ft%29%2C%28u%2C1%2Fu%29%7D%2Cx%5D)

Comment: Oh I got it! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple formula:

$$f(X) = \frac{1}{X} \left( 1- \prod_{s \in S}(1-s^{-1}X)\right)$$

Note that this is an actual polynomial in $R[X]$. Indeed, denote by
$$g(X)=1- \prod_{s \in S}(1-s^{-1}X) \in R[X]$$
From $g(0)=0$ you can deduce that $g(X)$ is a multiple of $X$, in other words
$$g(X)=Xf(X)$$
for some $f \in R[X]$.

Finally, for all $s \in S$ you have $$sf(s) = g(s) = 1-0=1$$
i.e. $f(s)=s^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to some helpful comments, I got the answer (hopefully):

We can solve this problem using induction on the cardinality of $S$. If $S=\{s\}$ for some unit $s\in R$, then the polynomial $f(x)=s^{-1}$ is a solution.

Now let $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{> 1}$ and by the induction hypotheses assume that for every finite set $T\subset R$ consisting of $n-1$ units there exists a polynomial $g$ such that $g(t)=t^{-1}$ for all $t\in T$. Now let $S=\{s_1,...,s_n\}\subset R$ be a subset of units. Define $g\in R[X]$ such that $g(s)=s^{-1}$ holds for all $s\in S\setminus \{s_n\}$. Also define $f\in R[X]$ by: $f(x)=-s_n^{-1}g(x)x+s_n^{-1}+g(x)$. This is well-defined and for all $i=1,...,n$ we have $f(s_i)=s_i^{-1}$ (For this part it is necessary that $R$ is commutative). Hence, it is also possible for $n$ elements and the induction is complete.